# Problems installing DSx Desktop

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx-desktop

I have problems installing DSx Desktop in my laptop. I have Docker Running (Kitematic), do I have to run Docker daemon in a certain way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of DSX Desktop may not support the legacy Docker solution that was bundled with Kitematic and DSX Desktop is probably looking for Docker for Mac.

The latest version of DSX Desktop does, however, provide support for Docker Toolbox, the version bundled into Kitematic. Upgrading to the latest version of DSX should allow you to complete the installation without you having to do anything in Kitematic. If you do not wish to upgrade to a newer version of DSX Desktop, you would need to upgrade to using [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/).