# Cannot install DSX Desktop on Mac - Siera

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx-desktop

Cannot install DSX Desktop on Mac - Siera
It is stuck at this
[image]

I have docker running

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out from
[Problems installing DSx Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158117/problems-installing-dsx-desktop)

i needed to do two things:-

1. Update kitematic on my Mac to latest which updated my docker version
2. I also had Oracle virtual machine installed, so for some reason, docker image for dsx-desktop needed to be started manually from oracle virtual machine.
   When i started it manually the installation proceeded.

Thanks,
Charles.